# How to return Stencil VNode element in React?

Tags: reactjs, stenciljs, stencil-component

Does anybody know whether it is possible to return the VNode element in React application as the property of the Stencil-based component?

The idea behind it is to use the property as `React.ReactNode` but in Stencil.

I have tried

```
  return h('button');
```

However, I can see errors in console.

Comment: hi, what exactly are you trying to achieve here? If you want to use your Stencil JS component inside React app but then somehow want to reference your React component within Stencil component, I would imagine using <slot/> would be cleanest way but I guess it's all depends on your use cases and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @tomokat,I’d like to achieve the 1st option without slots. That’s just a question if it possible in theory.

Comment: I see - well, if you are already aware about <slot/> but still want to do this, I'm sure you have a reason behind this. Hopefully someone can chime in as my exposure to React is very limited (I'm more familiar with AngularJS/Angular)